# Print date from MongoDB in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have two objects in the db with diferent dates:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5addeaf92602ff20497e9406"),
"success" : true,
"timestamp" : 1524477784,
"base" : "EUR",
"date" : "2018-04-22",
"rates" : {
    "AED" : 4.492662,
    "ALL" : 128.39508,
    "AMD" : 586.837094}
```

and the second one:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5addb57d0043582d48ba898a"),
"success" : true,
"timestamp" : 1524477784,
"base" : "EUR",
"date" : "2018-04-23",
"rates" : {
    "AED" : 4.492662,
    "ALL" : 128.39508,
    "AMD" : 586.837094}
```

My python code:

```
import pymongo

uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
database = client['db']
collection = database['currency']

d=(*something I guess*)(input('Insert date: '))
item = collection.find_one({})
data= item['date']['d']
print(data)
```

What I want is to insert a day or a specific date, and then the program would print that specific day info. 
In the db the date is in String and I think that I have to convert it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: date is a field in your document which in mongodb. if you are updating it you can display it also. elaborate more on your requirement

Comment: Well, first of all `data= item['date']['d']` this will not gona work because the 2nd `[]` is used for indexing. And in your case its up to you either you take input same as your string date or convert it into date the take input then put a check on it

Comment: @AbdullahAhmedGhaznavi and how can I do one of those things?

Comment: @FilipeVarandas: check the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all `data= item['date']['d']` this will not gona work because the 2nd `[]` is used for indexing. And in your case its up to you either you take input same as your string date or convert it into date the take input then put a check on it

**For converting string into date do this:**

```
from datetime import date
year, month, day = map(int, (d['date']).split("-"))
required_date = date(year, month, day)
print required_date
```

**Note:** assuming that i have your mongo object/dictionary in `d`

**and for second case:**

take input from user in the same format in string for e.g:

```
userinput = str(raw_input('Enter Date: in Format(year, month, day) with seprator "-" e.g: 2018-04-23 \n'))

if userinput == d['date']:
    print 'Correct'
```

again assuming that `d` is your mongo object.

**Note:** 
Its for exmaple what ever case you are using use then put a `if` check on it.

Hope it helps you! :)